# Entity Framework 4.1 and practical use in an existing application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ddd-repositories

I saw many videos around about EF and still I can't find the proper way of approaching this tool in my project.
Everywhere the are speaking about two situations, first you have a DB and no Domain model, second, you have the DM and no DB.

I have an already up and running application with well defined DM and DB. I have the repositories interfaces defined and I have a concrete implementation of this repositories, using a simple SQL queries.

Now, I'm tiered of this antique approach and I would like start using EF.

However I can't find a way of start implementing a concrete repository via EF.

Can you suggest me a proper approach?

This is an example of my current situation:

A partial extract of class

```
public class Order : IAggregateRoot
{
    protected Order()
    {
        this._Items = new List<OrderItem>();
        this.Date = null; ;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an order for a given customer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="customer">The customer</param>
    /// <returns>An order</returns>
    public static Order CreateOrder(Customer customer)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(customer != null, "customer");

        Order order = new Order();
        order.Customer = customer;

        return order;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ship name
    /// </summary>
    [StringLengthValidator(40)]
    public virtual string ShipName { get; set; }
```

Order repository interface

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the repository of objects of type Order
/// </summary>
public interface IOrderRepository : IRepository<Order>
{
}
```

Database table where all this is stored is has a strange naming convention (in Dutch) called ordenen with columns having particular names etc.

Now how can I implement a repository via EF?

Any suggestions is welcome!

Cheers!

Comment: It should be better for you to start with some test or POC application to understand the basics of EF because at this point it looks like you are asking how to implement the repository but you have no idea how does the mapping work and that is simply something we cannot explain in single answer. Start with some tutorial.

Comment: Can you suggest me a good tutorial or article? I need to map existing DM to existing DB, and I didn't yet found any video that explains how to deal with a situation like this. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to use code mapping or EDMX file? Btw. when you have both classes and database you can end in situation where EF is simply not able to do a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very neat Tutorial on asp.net website that will help you get up and running using EF 4.1 Code-first or POCO. It's [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) and will help you understand everything in no more than one day.

For detailed building of applications using EF, repositories and testing. You can go through this book named [PRO Asp.net MVC3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005PZ07US) by Steven Sanderson